# Ads Mediation (admob + FAN)?

Tags: android, admob

i have  added FAN ads to my apps and all things are working well and good, their are native ads i have used as the FAN ads, the placement ids are live and the request are been recorded well.

But now i have to use AdMob mediation , 
my questions are : Any help will be appreciated

**Do i have to remove all the code of my FAN ads which i have implemented  and add the Google Admob ads and then link the ad units to the facebook units in the admob console?**

**their is no option to add "native ads" source group at admob mediation panel see image below. and if i do Admob Mediation do i have to write the code for AdMob Ads , the documentation is not well explained in the site**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AdMob [native ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-advanced) is currently in a limited release. You will not be able to mediate between FAN and AdMob using this format for now.